# add multiple cookie schemes in aspnet core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

How to add multiple cookie schemes in `aspnet core 2.0`?

I've followed instructions from here [Auth 2.0 Migration announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310) 
and here [Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) 
but i am unable to add multiple schemes.

*for example*:

```
services.AddAuthentication("myscheme1").AddCookie(o =>{
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/forUser");
        o.Cookie.Name = "token1";
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

services.AddAuthentication("myscheme2").AddCookie(o =>{
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/forAdmin");
        o.Cookie.Name = "token2";
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding multiple schemes in `aspnet core 2.0` is simple. 
I've solved by doing this.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie("myscheme1", o => // scheme1
{
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/forUser");
        o.Cookie.Name = "token1";
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddCookie("myscheme2", o => //scheme2
{
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/forAdmin");
        o.Cookie.Name = "token2";
        o.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

discussion can be found here [Auth 2.0 Migration announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310#issuecomment-323931462)